# Header Responsiveness issue

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-transitions

I am trying to make the header for a site but i have a issue when it comes to responsiveness on height.

And something i am not sure that it can be resolved with media queries breakpoints as you can see from the photo below.
[image: issue]

and here is how it looks on full window

[image]

Html

```
 <body>
    <header class="header"> 
       <div class="logo-box"></div>
       <img src="/img/logo-white.png" class="logo">
       <div class="text-box">
          <h1 class="heading-primary">
             <span class="heading-primary-main">City</span>   
             <span class="heading-primary-sub">is where life happens</span>   
          </h1>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-white">Discover our City</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-white">Discover our Tours</a>
       </div> 
    </header>
 </body>
```

CSS

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.7;
    color: #777;
}

.header{
    height:65vh;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right  bottom, rgba(132,248,198 , 0.8), rgba(26,187,137,0.8)),url(../img/ch4.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: top;
    background-color:#4FD1A9;
}
.logo-box{
    position: absolute;
    top:40px;
    left:40px;
}

.logo{
    height:35px;
}

.heading-primary {
    color:#fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.heading-primary-main{
    display: block;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 35px;
}

.heading-primary-sub {
    display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.text-box {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top:30%;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50% ,-50%);
    text-align: center;
    
   
}

.btn:link, 
.btn:visited {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding:15px 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 100px;
    transition: all .2s;
    margin: 5px;
}

.btn:hover {
    transform: translateY(-3px);
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgb(0,0,0,.2);
}

.btn:active {
    transform: translateY(-1px) ;
}

.btn-white {
    background-color: #fff;
    color:#777;
}
```

Should i make the entire header with CSS grid Layout breaking it its own parts?

Comment: Looks like it’s been cut off as there isn’t enough space in the .header height. If you change the .header height to auto it’ll work.

Comment: I did but now even the desktop version "broke" and it doesnt show anything expect white and a super small line of green on the top

Comment: Sorry, on my mobile so not a proper response. I’d say you need to add heights into each of the sections once you used height: auto. This means the box will adapt to how tall the elements are within it.

Comment: thank you! interesting approach! Altough, i am wondering if i can achieve the same look and super web responsive if i just use Grid on the parent element (which is header) and then subgrids for other elements like logo, buttons and the text. So each element has its own space in the grid. 
Though i am not sure how the image will remain responsive without affecting the rest of Grid items

Comment: Could you give the dimensions of the viewport at which you're having difficulties?

Comment: Yes! around 598x550 it starts getting a mess and top of the header is collapsing when i dont want it to be collapsed but always visible doesnt matter how much the user collapses his window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is somewhat opinionated, but I think that's unavoidable for this kind of question as there's so many different ways that it could be done.

I take the view that the height of elements should be determined only by their contents. If it was the case that users were comfortable scrolling horizontally as well as vertically through a website, then responsive design would be a complete non-issue. Responsive Design only becomes necessary *because* we prevent horizontal scrolling. We should not therefore concern ourselves with the height of content, only with the width.

Accordingly, I've removed the fixed height from the header as well as the absolute positioning from some of the elements and allowed the content to be laid out according to the natural flow. For desktop, I think this works fine.

A slightly different approach is required for narrower screens since on these you *do* begin to have issues with the width of the content. My solution here is to introduce a break-point at around the point when the content starts to get too wide for the viewport. Then I set all dimensions - font-sizes, margins, padding etc - to be a proportion of the current viewport width. A little math is required here to calculate the correct values, and I've also used CSS Custom Properties to make things a bit DRYer. In fact, there's only one declaration within the media query, and that's to set the base-unit from which all other values are calculated.

I've made notes in the CSS giving the reasoning for some of the changes I've made.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.7;
  color: #777;
}

.header {
  --unit: 1px;
  /*  removing this since the height of an element should be determined by content */
  /* height:65vh;*/
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgba(132, 248, 198, 0.8), rgba(26, 187, 137, 0.8)), url(https://s.abcnews.com/images/Business/gty_detroit_mi_130718_4x3_992.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-color: #4FD1A9;
  /*
   * flexbox is the best way to layout content along a single axis
   * for various practical and performance reasons
   */
  display: flex;
}

.text-box {
  --padding-v: calc(var(--unit) * 50);
  --padding-h: calc(var(--unit) * 10);
  display: inline-block;
  padding: var(--padding-v) var(--padding-h);
  /* This content should just be in the normal flow of the page */
  /*
    position: absolute
    top:30%;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50% ,-50%);
  */
  text-align: center;
  /*  Because we're using flexbox, we can center the content both horizontally and vertically
   *  using this declaration
   */
  margin: auto;
}

.heading-primary {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.heading-primary-main {
  --font-size: calc(var(--unit) * 60);
  --letter-spacing: calc(var(--unit) * 35);
  display: block;
  font-size: var(--font-size);
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: var(--letter-spacing);
}

.heading-primary-sub {
  --font-size: calc(var(--unit) * 20);
  --letter-spacing: calc(var(--unit) * 15);
  --margin-bottom: calc(var(--unit) * 60);
  display: block;
  font-size: var(--font-size);
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: var(--letter-spacing);
  margin-bottom: var(--margin-bottom);
}

.btn {
  --padding-v: calc(var(--unit) * 15);
  --padding-h: calc(var(--unit) * 40);
  --border-radius: calc(var(--unit) * 100);
  --margin: calc(var(--unit) * 5);
  --font-size: calc(var(--unit) * 16);
  font-size: var(--font-size);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: var(--padding-v) var(--padding-h);
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: var(--border-radius);
  transition: all .2s;
  margin: var(--margin);
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #777;
}

.btn:hover {
  transform: translateY(-3px);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgb(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.btn:active {
  transform: translateY(-1px);
}


/*
 * This is around the point at which the text starts to wrap
 * 
 * We take a fundamentally different approach to layout here. Now we want dimensions to
 * scale with the width of the viewport so that it will look good at all sizes
 */

@media only screen and (max-width: 550px) {
  .header {
    --unit: calc(100vw / 550);
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="./header.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <header class="header">
    <div class="text-box">
      <h1 class="heading-primary">
        <span class="heading-primary-main">City</span>
        <span class="heading-primary-sub">is where life happens</span>
      </h1>
      <a href="#" class="btn">Discover our City</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn">Discover our Tours</a>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Oh my! It works like a charm! Especially on mobile version it work as it should! No overlapping of other content and everything it remains as it should on header! Though, the only issue that i encounter is that i have a background image on the header and when its on full viewport (desktop verson 1920x1080) the image is cropped on the bottom but as soon it hits the mobile view its displays the full image on low opacity in the green background of header....

Comment: `background-position` is the property for adjusting the background. I've added an image to the above and centered it using this.

Comment: thank you! it looks like a charm now! I wish i could hire you occasionally as mentor since i am quite Junior Web Dev! 
Though, now i am building the entire Layout on Grid and even the various sections of the site using subgrids even for the most simple things like FAQ section or even small photo gallery and i think its quite easy technique and safe for web responsiveness

Comment: haha, thank you. I'm here pretty often, and I think you'll find a lot of people on this site equally happy to help you. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Use `media-quires` to adjust your layout.

Problem occurs due to `position:absolute`

[Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.7;
    color: #777;
}

.header{
    height:65vh;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right  bottom, rgba(132,248,198 , 0.8), rgba(26,187,137,0.8)),url(../img/ch4.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: top;
    background-color:#4FD1A9;
}
.logo-box{
    position: absolute;
    top:40px;
    left:40px;
}

.logo{
    height:35px;
}

.heading-primary {
    color:#fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.heading-primary-main{
    display: block;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 35px;
}

.heading-primary-sub {
    display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.text-box {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top:30%;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50% ,-50%);
    text-align: center;
    
   
}

.btn:link, 
.btn:visited {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding:15px 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 100px;
    transition: all .2s;
    margin: 5px;
}

.btn:hover {
    transform: translateY(-3px);
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgb(0,0,0,.2);
}

.btn:active {
    transform: translateY(-1px) ;
}

.btn-white {
    background-color: #fff;
    color:#777;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .header {
       height: 100vh;//adjust as per your req
  }
  .text-box {
    display: block; 
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transform: none;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
}
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header class="header"> 
       <div class="logo-box"></div>
       <img src="/img/logo-white.png" class="logo">
       <div class="text-box">
          <h1 class="heading-primary">
             <span class="heading-primary-main">City</span>   
             <span class="heading-primary-sub">is where life happens</span>   
          </h1>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-white">Discover our City</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-white">Discover our Tours</a>
       </div> 
    </header>
 </body>
```

Comment: i have added comment that use `height` as per req  `.header {
       height: 100%;
  }`

Comment: Oh my! now i works like a charm! Though would you suggest for this type of site and design another design approach like CSS grid layout?

Comment: Yes rather the `postion:absolute` use `display:flex` to achieve above type of results. Ref link for further understanding `https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/`  more modern easy to handle browser compatible responsive and much more

Comment: btw with height:auto on your media queries it works better since when i adjust if for example 65vh the buttons are collapsing out of the header picture although the top stays fixed and doesnt collapse

Comment: yes i know. I am just following a tutorial that had this super interesting design with css3 animations but it doesnt use flex and css grid  layout rather than the old method of float design since back in 2017 flexbox and css grid layout werent yet popular.

Comment: Hahah no prob @Nick87 use what is easier and understandable for you :) Best of luck